# Minimizer of a function containing response and predicting variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, differential-geometry, optimization

Can anyone please give me the expression of the "minimizer" of $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \vert y_i - b x_i \vert + \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - b x_i)^2 \quad \quad ?$$

I am unable to find this expression on the internet. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Here, $y_i$'s are response variables and $x_i$'s are predictor variables.

Comment: you are  looking for a value of $b$ that minimizes this sum, right?

Comment: yes, exactly ! that's what I am looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ to get $|x|'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x}{|x|}=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ for $x\ne 0$.

Define 
$$f(b)=\sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{( y_i - b x_i )^2} + \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - b x_i)^2$$

differentiate to get
$$f'(b)=-\sum_{i = 1}^n \,x_i\mathrm{sgn}( y_i - b x_i ) - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - b x_i)x_i
$$
and
$$f''(b)=-2\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2
$$

Note that $f'$ and $f''$ aren't defined at $y_i=b x_i,\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots n\}$. 
Since since $f''(b)<-0$ except finite number of points, than for $b$'s such that $f'(b)=0$ we have a local minimum. We also may have an extremum at points of singularity, i.e. at $b$'s such that $y_i=b x_i, i\in\{1,2,\dots n\}$.

There is no analytical solution to $f'(b)=0$ unless you have additional information about response/predictor variables. So you probably should use numerical approach. For example ([Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) or [Secant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) iteration), 
$$b_{n+1}=b_n-\frac{f'(b_n)}{f''(b_n)}$$
or
$$b_{n+1}=b_n-\frac{f'(b_n)(b_{n+1}-b_n)}{f'(b_{n+1}-f'(b_n))}$$

You could also do some trial and error to find values $a, c$ such that $\mathrm{sgn}f(a)\ne \mathrm{sgn}f(b)$ and try [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), which doesn't require to differentiate anything.

To find a global minimum you should work harder. You need to determine all values of $b$ for which $y_i=b x_i$ for some $i$. Denote these values $b_i$ and order them such that $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$. Find value of $f(b_i)$. Find minimum (if exists) between all $(b_i,b_{i+1})$. Finally, compare between all these $2n$ values $f(b_i)$ to find the smallest one. It could happen that $b_i$ that give a minimal value of $f(b_i)$ is not unique.

Comment: thank you very much, Sir, for the above solution !!! Thank you very much especially for explaining it so clearly !! :-)

Comment: you welcome, Note, I missed the $(-\infty, b_1)$ and $(b_n,\infty)$ for a global case.